# c# Socket not timing out

Tags: .net, sockets, c#-4.0

I have the following c# code to query whois servers, occasionally I will hit a server and the socket will never time out the Receive (unfortunately if I hit the same server again all of a sudden the problem goes away). I have set the ReceiveTimeout value though, anyone know what is going wrong here?

```
string whoisServer = "whois.moniker.com";
Socket s = null;
IPAddress ipAddress;
ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(whoisServer).AddressList[0];                

s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
s.SendTimeout = 10000;
s.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 43));
s.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(domain + "\r\n"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int recv = s.Receive(buffer);
while (recv > 0)
{
    ret += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);
    recv = s.Receive(buffer);
}
s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
s.Close();
```

Comment: Wait a minute, you mean it's staying on the line `s.Receive` forever?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the DNS query that's hanging? Just a thought.

Comment: @Lazarus: There also is a SendTimeout.

Comment: When I pause the debugger it is stuck on the Receive line, forever (at least I have waited 30 minutes before stopping the debugger.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: That's for the socket. @meldo has clarified regardless.

Comment: Not really an answer to the problem, but I got around the problem by using the asyncronous version of the Receive command and implementing my own timeout.

Comment: I've got this same problem (with the same timeout, even [10s]). Will probably implement my own timeout, as well, unless somebody has found a solution..?